# IF Statement in Adobe Arobat PDF Form

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a field which calculates the value of three integers named 'TotalScore'. I then need to produce an IF Statement to work out based on the value in TotalScore the outcome of a performance. For example:

If TotalScore > 90 then OverallMatchPerformance = "Well Above Expected"
If TotalScore > 80 then OverallMatchPerformance = "Above Expected"
..

This is what I have so far:

```
var TotalScore = TotalScore

if(TotalScore > 90)
    console.log("Well Above Expected");
```

Every time I enter this into the 'Custom Calculation Script' in Adobe PDF I am not getting any results. How do I produce this statement above?

Most recent update:

```
var TotalScore = TotalScore.rawValue
if (TotalScore > 90){
   console.log("Well Above Standard")}
```

[This is where I am trying to display the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0jWI.png)
TotalScore is the variable and OverallMatchPerformance is where the output needs to be displayed "Well Above Standard"

[Latest Update - 20:26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYgH4.png)

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: whats the problem / question?

Comment: I need to produce an If statement for a PDF document in the 'Custom Calculation Script'. Each time I try no values return.

Comment: `var TotalScore = TotalScore` is a problem.  If TotalScore is already in scope, you do not need the declaration, just use it directly.  Also, try `TotalScore.rawValue` as I believe the underlying value is stored in the `rawValue` property while TotalScore is an XFAObject

Comment: @Dave 'var TotalScore = TotalScore.rawValue
if (TotalScore > 90){
   console.log("Well Above Standard")}'

This doesn't seem to work

Comment: try `console.log(TotalScore);` by itself, what does it produce?

Comment: @Dave - nothing, which is confusing.

Comment: IIRC it’s console.println, not console.log

Comment: @Dave Still not working. I have updated the post with another image. Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

try switching `console.log("Well Above Standard")` for `return "Well Above Standard"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't worked either

Comment: Check this post out: https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Return-text-based-calculated-field-q137580.aspx

it covers exactly what you are looking for